# Getting to Petra from Amman in Jordan

Tags: jordan, petra

Let's say I fly into Queen Alia International Airport / Amman in Jordan. How would I get to Petra without renting a car?

[Apparently there's a bus](http://www.jett.com.jo/SubPage.aspx?PageId=230) that'll take me from Abdali to Petra. Where's Abdali? wikipedia.org suggests that Abdali is, among other things, "Abdali Urban Regeneration Project, district in Amman, Jordan". That's nice, but saying the bus departs from there is about as useful as saying "we have a bus stop in Jordan; find it". Abdali is presumably a large district and scouring the whole district for one bus stop...  seems like a bit of a waste of time.

Maybe I could [use a service like this](http://www.viajordan.com/extra_pages.php?page_name=Petra%20from%20Amman&page_id=189) but it's not clear to me how that'd work. Do I just pick up a hotel and they'll pick me up from it? Do they pick the hotel? And if they're providing the food what kind of food do they have?

Comment: Welcome to the site. I tidied up your question a bit, and removed the question about restaurants - as per our [faq], questions should be separated, but feel free to ask a new question about that.  Note that there's Petra - the historic site, and Petra, a town right next to it, and as with any town, there are usually places to eat (indeed I ate at a restaurant when I was there).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Abdali, Tabarbour, 7th Circle and Al-wehda are all names of bus stations in Amman](http://wikitravel.org/en/Amman#By_bus).

Abdali is located near the King Abdullah Mosque.

How to get there? I'd just take taxi. However, it's good idea to make sure of the price before you get in. Don't let them rip you off. [Wikitravel suggests that directly from the airport it ought to be around 20 dinars](http://wikitravel.org/en/Amman#By_plane), I remember that when I went, had no idea how much it should be and ended up overpaying (paid something like 50 dinars). Taxi within city is just a couple of dinars. There is really no valid reason not to use them.

BTW. instead of going just to Petra and back to Amman, you might consider staying for a night there and see [Wadi Rum](http://wikitravel.org/en/Wadi_Rum) the other day. The problem is the bus again, but you can take taxi, which should be reasonably priced.

Comment: I did a Google Maps search for Abdali Amam and my best guess is that the bus station would be somewhere around here but I'm not completely positive: http://goo.gl/maps/voxvn

Comment: How much do you think a taxi to Petra from Amman would cost (assuming that that's what you were proposing)? Google Maps suggests that it's 241km, est ETA 3h 26 min. Seems like a taxi ride that was that long would be $$.

Comment: Also, I can't find any info on Petra the city on wikipedia. My Google maps search suggest that the closest town is El Gi.

Comment: Amman hasn't got Streetview, but it has got satelite view: http://goo.gl/maps/U94r2 that looks like a bus station to me. As for taxi, I didn't mean taxi from Petra to Amman, but taxi from Petra to Wadi Rum. Still a bit of a ride (115km). Petra City as you call it is a small town called Wadi Musa.

Comment: Of course taxis aren't cheapest way of travel if you're traveling alone. Sharing a taxi between 4 people OTOH is quite affordable alternative.

Answer (score 2):

You can go with very good bus special for tourist called Jett. This bus departure from many places in Amman (contact them for details) at 6:30 AM.

For more information call them they can speak English and Arabic. To see the schedule check the link below.

http://www.jett.com.jo/SubPage.aspx?PageId=230